# Node-xmpp: Cannot read propery 'write' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-xmpp

I'm having an issue with node-xmpp, server-side settings out of my control maybe have changed but this error is relatively new. Looking for some pointers/insight, I've not been able to solve this issue within the module or my code. I unfortunately cannot provide my code to troubleshoot, however, it's on the simple xmpp.Client/send method. It's failing about 80% of the time is the kicker.

Thanks

> **Cannot read property 'write' of undefined**
>      at lib/node/.npm/ltx/0.0.5/package/lib/element.js:197:22
>      at Array.forEach (native)
>
> at Element.write (lib/node/.npm/ltx/0.0.5/package/lib/element.js:196:23)
>      at lib/node/.npm/ltx/0.0.5/package/lib/element.js:198:23
>      at Array.forEach (native)
>
> at Element.write (lib/node/.npm/ltx/0.0.5/package/lib/element.js:196:23)
>      at lib/node/.npm/ltx/0.0.5/package/lib/element.js:198:23
>      at Array.forEach (native)
>
> at Element.write (lib/node/.npm/ltx/0.0.5/package/lib/element.js:196:23)
>      at Client.send (lib/node/.npm/**node-
>   xmpp/0.2.10/package/lib/xmpp/connection.js:76:12**)

Here's the source from connection.js in question:

```
Connection.prototype.send = function(stanza) {
if (!this.socket.writable) {
    this.socket.end();
    return;
}

if (stanza.root) {
    var el = this.rmStreamNs(stanza.root());
    var socket = this.socket;
    el.write(function(s) { socket.write(s); });  // LINE 76
    return el;
} else {
    this.socket.write(stanza);
    return stanza;
}
};
```